# Ignore object attribute when using signalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

i have a problem with ignoring an attribute so it doesn't get sent down to the client. I have this object

```
public class UserEntry : IComparable<UserEntry>
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public string AnonymousUserId { get; set; }
}
```

And i am having a problem for when for example i send a message to my signalR application the `UserId` is still in the data but i only want the `AnonymousUserId` to get sent down because the `UserId` is only used in the backend and shouldn't ever be in client.

so when i get here

```
    public Task TopUserBroadcast(TopUsersBroadcastNotificationModel model)
    {
        SignalRClient.SendAsync(SignalRAppMethods.Broadcast, Constants.GetInfoGroup(model.InfoId), ResponseMessageIDs.TopUsers,model.Entries);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

The `userId` is still in the `model.Entries`. Anyway i can make it ignore that attribute?

and the `TopUsersBroadcastNotificationModel` looks like this

```
public class TopUsersBroadcastNotificationModel
{
    public List<UserEntry> Entries { get; set; }

    public long InfoId { get; set; }

    public TopUsersBroadcastNotificationModel(List<UserEntry> entries, long InfoId)
    {
        Entries = entries;
        InfoId = infoId;
    }
}
```

So what i really want and hoped the `[JsonIgnore]` would solve is that when its sent down to the client the UserId should be ignored so if i log the entries i get down to client there should be no UserId there.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a function as following in your entity :

```
public bool ShouldSerializeXXXX() { return false; }
```

change the `XXXX` to your attribute name .

in your case `UserId`:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeUserId() { return false; }
```

If you need to make it dynamic you can input a static boolean value in the return field and change it when you need

**EDIT**

about your comment , this is what working in my case : 
i have a person class with fingerprint as a string field , and i didn't want to send it to by a SignalR hub or even a webservices , but by using an specific action to get the fingerprint , so what considere a entity `person` with attributs fingerprint as following

```
public string fingerprint { get; set; }
```

i added this method :

```
public bool ShouldSerializefingerprint() { return ShouldSerializefingerprintTest; }
```

the `ShouldSerializefingerprintTest` field is a static boolean attributs who can be edited to true or false 
by default is false so the fingerprint will not be showen on any webservice/signalR

and when i need to get the fingerprint `ShouldSerializefingerprintTest` to `true`
but   `public bool ShouldSerializefingerprint() { return false; }` can do what you need.

you can find more on [microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/defining-default-values-with-the-shouldserialize-and-reset-methods).

Comment: How would this remove/ignore the attribute before sending it down? do you have an example on where to call this and how it works?